# JQuery AJAX: Debugging JSON Parse Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am looking if someone can walk through the process of debugging a JSON parse error returned by the browser upon making an HTTP POST request. I'm providing an error I am currently stumped on but an answer that might be more widely applicable to similar problems may make this post even more valuable to the community.

**Details**

I am using JQuery's AJAX method within a React application to send an HTTP POST request to an IoT resource over the web. The resource is an RGB LED and its model includes a "value:" field that takes an array of 3 integers each between 0~255 that define the LED's intensity for each color (e.g. `"value": [0, 255, 0]`). Upon sending a payload of, or what I believe to be of, `"value": [0, 255, 0]` using an HTTP POST, the following error is returned.

**Console Error**

```
undefined "parsererror" "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"
(anonymous) @ LEDComponent.jsx?cf20:21
j @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
x @ jquery.min.js:4
b @ jquery.min.js:4
```

Below please, find the source code and XHR headers, the ladder being reported by Chrome.

**Source Code (Relevant Function)**

*Note: The URL shown is a live resource with limited R(GET)/W(POST) permissions open to everyone (no authentication required). You can try hitting the resource with Postman for more information or use it for reproducing the problem, testing fixes, etc.*

```js
handleOnButtonClick: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://devices.webofthings.io/pi/actuators/leds/rgbled1/',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify({"value": [0, 255, 0]}),
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({ledStatus: 'ON'});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**XHR Headers**

```
Request URL:http://devices.webofthings.io/pi/actuators/leds/rgbled1/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:202 Accepted
Remote Address:62.252.146.178:80
Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Thu, 09 Mar 2017 11:10:26 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Origin
X-Powered-By:Express
Request Headers
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:19
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:devices.webofthings.io
Origin:null
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Mobile Safari/537.36
Form Data
{"value":[0,255,0]}:
Name
rgbled1/
1 requests ❘ 220 B transferred
```

Comment: Maybe the endpoint expects an array of objects, not a single object?

Comment: I am somewhat concerned about the `:` being appended to `{"value":[0,255,0]}` during the parsing process. I think that's suspect. Perhaps this is an issue with how the `.stringify` method is being leveraged?

Comment: See "Form Data" in the XHR Headers.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Add `contentType: 'application/json',` to the request options.

```js
handleOnButtonClick: function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://devices.webofthings.io/pi/actuators/leds/rgbled1/',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
      "value": [0, 255, 0]
    }),
    success: function(data) {
      this.setState({
        ledStatus: 'ON'
      });
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
      console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
    }.bind(this)
  });
},
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

After making the change and testing it you should see the JSON being properly parsed in Chrome's dev tools.

**XHR Headers**

```
...
{value: [0, 255, 0]}
value
:
[0, 255, 0]
0:0
1:255
2:0
```